# Entity Framework Lazy loading performance comparison

Tags: c#, performance, database, entity-framework

The following code takes about 20 seconds to run with about 200,000 records in the TaskLogs table:

```
using (var db = new DAL.JobManagerEntities())
    {
        return db.TaskLogs.Select(taskLog => new TaskLog()
        {
            TaskLogID = taskLog.TaskLogID,
            TaskID = taskLog.TaskID,
            TaskDescription = taskLog.Task.TaskDescription,
            TaskType = (TaskType)taskLog.Task.TaskTypeID,
            RunID = taskLog.RunID,
            ProcessID = taskLog.ProcessID,
            JobID = taskLog.JobID,
            JobName = taskLog.Job.JobName,
            Result = taskLog.Result,
            StartTime = taskLog.StartTime,
            TimeTaken = taskLog.TimeTaken
        }).OrderByDescending(t => t.RunID).ThenByDescending(t => t.RunID).ThenByDescending(t => t.StartTime).ToList();
    }
```

I tweaked it until I got something that runs faster. Here's where I got to:

```
            using (var db = new DAL.JobManagerEntities())
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        var tasks = db.Tasks.ToList();
        var jobs = db.Jobs.ToList();
        var result = db.TaskLogs.Select(x => new TaskLog()
        {
            TaskLogID = x.TaskLogID,
            TaskID = x.TaskID,
            RunID = x.RunID,
            ProcessID = x.ProcessID,
            JobID = x.JobID,
            Result = x.Result,
            StartTime = x.StartTime,
            TimeTaken = x.TimeTaken
        }).OrderByDescending(t => t.RunID).ThenByDescending(t => t.StartTime).ToList();

        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            r.TaskDescription = tasks.Single(t => t.TaskID == r.TaskID).TaskDescription;
            r.TaskType = (TaskType)tasks.Single(t => t.TaskID == r.TaskID).TaskTypeID;
            r.JobName = jobs.Single(j => j.JobID == r.JobID).JobName;
        }
        return result;}
```

Which runs in less than 6 seconds for the same number of records.

The TaskLog table is linked to the Job and Task tables as follows: 
[image]

The Job and Task tables will have 100s and 1000s of records respectively.

Is there anything else I could do in order to further improve the efficiency of the code?

Comment: I don't see why you think you need LazyLoading in the first solution. Things like server side `taskLog.Task.TaskDescription` will be handled just fine without lazy loading. Can you disable LazyLoading and Proxy creation for the first sample as well as using `AsNoTracking`? Would be interesting whether this boosts performance.

Comment: That improved the performance by about 1.5 seconds, but still nothing compared to the second version of the code, especially when combined with the answer from @JanDotNet

Comment: This is very strange... is there any noteworthy difference when you create an anonymous result type (`Select(taskLog => new { ... })` instead of `new TaskLog() ...`) and don't cast the `TaskTypeID` but take it as the returned type? Below you commented that the query runs in like 15ms, rest being the `ToList`... how did you test this, it sounds a bit fast?

Comment: Did you check the generated query (inspect it eg. with `db.Database.Log = x => WriteSomewhere(x)` and check query performance with some dedicated SQL tool for comparison)

Comment: Is there any *LOB datatype involved for example for the `TaskDescription`?

Comment: @grek40 I am stepping through breakpoints in Visual Studio to see how long things take. I haven't compared the generated queries in details

Comment: Then the 15ms are not an interesting number. The query is only constructed, not executed until you write something like `ToList`

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Regarding the datatypes, here is a screenshot of all the columns of all the tables involved: [link](https://imgur.com/a/NV5Jh)

Comment: Ok, so worst case, `JobName` and `TaskDescription` sum up to 1000 characters per record, which is more than all the other properties combined. Since you mention  there will be a lot less entries (1000s vs 200000 records), the solution from @JanDotNet makes perfect sense, it will just transfer a lot less duplicated strings from server to client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Not sure if it impacts performance, but your first code fragment has one redunant order by:

```
.OrderByDescending(t => t.RunID).ThenByDescending(t => t.RunID)
```

2) You could improve performance of your seconds code with "client side indexing" (using a dictionary):

```
var tasksMap = tasks.ToDictionary(t => t.TaskID);
var jobsMap = jobs.ToDictionary(t => t.JobID);

foreach (var r in result)
{
    var task = tasksMap[r.TaskID];
    r.TaskDescription = task.TaskDescription;
    r.TaskType = (TaskType)task.TaskTypeID;
    r.JobName = jobsMap[r.JobID].JobName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would `var taskMap = db.Tasks.ToDictionary(t => t.TaskID)` be the same as `var tasks = db.Tasks.ToList(); var taskMap = tasks.ToDictionary(t => t.TaskID)`?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd expect it.

Comment: The client side indexing does improve performance indeed. Execution time for the foreach loop went from about 500ms to about 30ms!

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things to speed this query up:

- use `join`s so that the entire query runs on the server and you don't have to run over the results again with the `foreach` loop
- add `.AsNoTracking()` to each table so that EF does not have to create proxy objects for change-tracking.

Here's an example of how it would look like when we apply both suggestions.

```
using (var db = new DAL.JobManagerEntities())
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var result = 
        from taskLog in db.TaskLogs.AsNoTracking()
        join task in db.Tasks.AsNoTracking() on taskLog.TaskID equals task.TaskID
        join job in db.Jobs.AsNoTracking() on taskLog.JobID equals job.JobID
        orderby taskLog.RunID descending, taskLog.StartTime descending
        select new TaskLog
        {
            TaskLogID = taskLog.TaskLogID,
            TaskID = taskLog.TaskID,
            RunID = taskLog.RunID,
            ProcessID = taskLog.ProcessID,
            JobID = taskLog.JobID,
            Result = taskLog.Result,
            StartTime = taskLog.StartTime,
            TimeTaken = taskLog.TimeTaken,
            TaskDescription = task.TaskDescription,
            TaskType = (TaskType)task.TaskTypeID,
            JobName = job.JobName
        };


    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answet! I’m going to try this later on and let you know

Comment: I had to make a few changes to make the above code work: `join job in db.Jobs.AsNoTracking() on taskLog.JobID equals job.TaskID` needs to be `join job in db.Jobs.AsNoTracking() on taskLog.JobID equals job.JobID` and I also need to order the result before returning `return result.OrderByDescending(t => t.RunID).ThenByDescending(t => t.StartTime).ToList();`. Unfortunately this code runs in about 20 seconds, so it is much slower than the original one.

Comment: @demonicdaron Yeah, I thougt so that I might have the IDs wrong - but this was notepad-coding ;-] If this is even slower then most probably because you order it again. There is already an `orderby` that will run on the server. No need to do it locally again.

Comment: sorry I completely missed that order by! for some reasons it wasn't returning the same data as the original code, so I added the order by and that corrected the problem. I'm gonna do some more testing and come back to your answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: I just tried removing the order by altogether (both from the query and the return), but it made little difference. I also removed the where clause, but that also had little effect.

Comment: @demonicdaron but there is/was no `where` in your question :-| maybe you should also reactivate the `LazyLoadingEnabled`

Comment: @t3chbot You are right there was no `where`, sorry about that. I am also testing another overload of the same function that takes a date in. The code is identical for both overloads apart from the `where`. I am going to try to re-enable lazy loading and see if that helps.

Comment: @t3chbot unfortunately removing the line that disabled `LazyLoadingEnabled` didn't have any positive effect. The code takes 20-30 seconds to run

Comment: @demonicdaron this is really strange. This query should execute in no time :-\ make sure you measure it more then once. The first run is always slower because the query itself needs to be compiled.

Comment: @t3chbot after some more testing, I can see that the query runs in 15ms, but `return result.ToList()` takes about 15 seconds to execute. [I run the same code about 3-4 times before saying how long it takes to run.]

Comment: @demonicdaron there is still one more bug in this query, I now see... here `taskLog.JobID equals job.TaskID`, this should be both `JobID`, this might be the reason what it's still too slow. I joins invalid keys.

Comment: I corrected that in the code I'm running. I tried to edit the answer to correct that, but it needs to be peer reviewed before the edit takes effect

Comment: @demonicdaron yes, I saw the first correction and have already accepted it. In the subsequent edits I guess I didn't see you corrected the other ID too.